# How to read numbers from a mixed txt file in python

Tags: python, list, text, types, reader

I have a txt file which is composed of text and numbers. It looks something like this:

```
> this is a paragraph which is introductory which lasts
  some more lines 

text text text

567 45 32 468
974 35 3578 4467
325 765 355 5466

text text text
1 3 6
text text>
```

What i need is to store the rows which contains 4 number elements.

When i use the read command all elements are read and stored as strings. I'm not sure if i can convert the numbers into digits without filtering them first.

I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: if so, dont forget to tick the answer that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to use python regex module you can do that:

```py
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open(TEST_FILE, 'r') as file_1:
        for line in file_1.readlines():

            if re.match(r'(\d+\s){4}', line): 
                line = line.strip() # remove \n character
                print(line) # just lines with four numbers are printed
```

The result for you file example is:

```sh
567 45 32 468
974 35 3578 4467
325 765 355 5466
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the splitlines() function.

```
A=open(your file here,'r').read().splitlines()
```

This will be a list and now you can extract whatever you need.
Like:

```py
Req=[]
for i in A:
    elem = [s.isnumeric() for s in i.split(' ')]
    if len(elem) == 4 and all(elem):
        Req.append(i)
```

Comment: `"123 321".isnumeric()` does not evaluate to `true`, so this is not a valid way to locate lines with numbers. You would have to split each line and check every element for numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Read file by lines, and analyse them. Skip lines with unequal 4 elements and lines that do not consist of 4 space seperated integers:

```
results = []
with open (filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split()
        if len(line) != 4:
            continue  # line has != 4 elements

        try: 
            numbers = map(int,line)
        except ValueError:
            continue # line is not all numbers

        # do something with line
        results.append(line)  # or append(list(numbers)) to add the integers

print(*results, sep="\n")
```

prints:

```
['567', '45', '32', '468']
['974', '35', '3578', '4467']
['325', '765', '355', '5466']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the rows you need will only have 4 numbers then this solution should work:

```
nums = []
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        if len(line) == 4 and all([c.isdigit() for c in line]):
            # use [float(c) for c in line] if needed
            nums.append([int(c) for c in line])

print(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds like task for `re` module. I would do:

```
import re
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
lines_w_4_numbers = re.findall(r'^\d+\s\d+\s\d+\s\d+$', txt, re.M)
print(lines_w_4_numbers)
```

Output:

```
['567 45 32 468', '974 35 3578 4467', '325 765 355 5466']
```

Explanation: `re.M` flag mean `^` and `$` will match start/end of line, `\s` denotes whitespace, `\d+` denotes 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for a substring that contains *exactly* four integers seperated by space and ended with a newline. You can use regular expressions to locate substrings that follows this pattern. Say you stored the string in the variable `s`:

```py
import re
matches = [m[0] for m in re.findall(r"((\d+\s){4})", s)]
```

The `matches` variable now contains the strings with exactly four integers in them. Afterwards you can split each string and convert to integers if you want:

```py
matches = [[int(i) for i in s.split(' ')] for s in matches]
```

Result:

```py
[[567, 45, 32, 468], [974, 35, 3578, 4467], [325, 765, 355, 5466]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression here will be most powerful. We create an pattern using re.compile and then we use search or match method to match the pattern in the string.

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'[\d]{4}') # \d matches for single digit and {4} will look for 4 continuous occurrences.
file = open('data.txt', 'r') # Opening the file
line_with_digits = [] 
for line in file:  # reading file line by line
    if p.search(line): # searching for pattern in line
        line_with_digits.append(line.strip())  # if pattern matches adding to list

print(line_with_digits)
```

The input file for above program is:

```
text text text

567 45 32 468
974 35 3578 4467
325 765 355 5466

text text text
1 3 6
text text

text  5566 text 45 text
text text 564 text 458 25 text
```

The output is:

```
['974 35 3578 4467', '325 765 355 5466', 'text  5566 text 45 text']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

result = []
with open('file_name.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if re.search(r'\d{4}', line):
            result.append(line.strip())

print(result)
```

output:

```
['974 35 3578 4467', '325 765 355 5466']
```